# "using" statement vs. curly brackets

Tags: c#, scope, using, curly-braces

I wonder why we do use `using` statement in C#. I looked it up, and found that it is used for executing the statements and then cleaning up the objects. So my question: Isn't it the same thing if we open and close curly brackets( `{ }` ) to define a scope?

**Using statement:**

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
     SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
     conn.Open();
     using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
          while (dr.Read()) 
          // Do Something...
     }
}
```

**Curly Brackets:**

```
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
     SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
     conn.Open();
     {
          SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          while (dr.Read()) 
          // Do Something...
     }
}
```

Are there any significant differences between two methods?

Comment: What has this got to do with `c++`?

Comment: The curly brackets are used in C++ the way they are used in this question, thats why I got mixed up. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, *using* (which is legal if and only if the class implements `IDisposable` interface)

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
  // Some Code
  ...
}
```

is equal to this block of code

```
SqlConnection conn = null;

try {
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

  // Some Code
  ...
}
finally {
  if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, conn))
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

C# *doesn't have the same behavior* as C++ does, so *do not use* {...} pattern in C# as you do in C++:

```
{
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
  ...
  // Here at {...} block exit system's behavior is quite different:
  //
  // C++: conn destructor will be called, 
  // resources (db connection) will be safely freed
  //
  // C#:  nothing will have happened! 
  // Sometimes later on (if only!) GC (garbage collector) 
  // will collect conn istance and free resources (db connection). 
  // So, in case of C#, we have a resource leak 
}
```

Comment: So it literally doesn't matter whether we use using or try/finally? Another question is that, as I recall, we can also use catch between try and finally. If we want to correspond that catch block, which part of using statement covers that?

Comment: Yes, you're quite right: using is just a syntactic sugar. If you put catch() into the same try {...} with finally {} it'll correspond to try {...} catch() {...} inside using() {...}: using (...) {try {...} catch() {...} }

Answer (score 3):

curly brackets just show a code of block

where as Using instructs the GC to dispose.

> Any class that implements IDisposable can be used with Using.

using will essentially translate to (note no catch). If there is any exception it will be thrown out. but even then connection will dispose

```
SqlConnection conn;
try
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
}
finally
{
    if (conn != null)
        conn.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

namespace changes name lookup whereas curly brackets create a new stack in which local variables may be created.

Comment: So using does not create a new stack to find local variables? Is that correct?

Comment: @Mert Toka : I was assuming it concerned C++. I see it has now been re-tagged to C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you use version with key ***using***, then NET platform runs method *Dispose* to free resources which the object used. So the object must implement *IDisposable* interface. In this way you free the resources in deterministic way (unlike *Garbage Collector* do it).

It is highly recommended to clean **NOT managed** resources in method *Dispose*, because *GC* does not clean it.

Curly brackets determine only the scope of variables used inside of them, but does not clean resources after the runtime reaches the close bracket. *GC* does it in non deterministic way according to its algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
using( ...){
... code
}
```

this is actually using pattern, c# compiler emits code to invoke the dispose method implemented by object created in the using block.

So for any object implementing IDisposable interface, you can use

```
using(var disposableObject = new DisposableObject()){
}
```

when this compiles compliler will generage code below

```
DisposableObject disposableObject = null;
try
{
   disposableObject = new DisposableObject();
}
finally{
   disposableObject.Dispose();
}
```

So using (..) statement ensure that dispose method of disposable object is called even if any exception is thrown within using statement.

Answer (score 0):

using is equivalent to following

```
SqlConnection conn;
try
{
   conn = new SqlConnection(connString)
}

finally
{
  conn.Dispose() //using does this automatically for you
}
```

> The rule is when some class implements `IDisposable` you can use USing
>   block instead of try catch, finally pattern

If you want more insight on how GC works, read this excellent article by [Jeffery Richter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)

Comment: yes, catch would not be there. It would be only try and finally

Comment: Does it actually replace `Try/Catch`? It only replaces the **explicit** call to `Dispose`?

Comment: What about the catch block? I mean, which part of the using block actually corresponds to catch block?

Comment: There is not one to one mapping between lines of code. So the entire block try and finally is equivalent to Using block

Comment: Technically, if an exception thrown within SqlConnection constructor (say, if connString is wrong) conn local variable will be underfined (it'll contain trash) and your code'll crash at the "finally". To reproduce "using" you should add "SqlConnection conn = null;" above "try"

Comment: the assignment should be outside of the try block